# Using $q.reject to stop chain from executing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pouchdb

In the code below, I am calling `Pouch.sync()`, to which I chain `deleteLocal()`. `Pouch.sync()` executes `localDb.sync()`, which does not return a promise, but I can attach a `.on()` event handler to handle errors.

I've tried playing around with $q.when and $q.reject, but I can't seem to prevent `deleteLocal()` from firing if the sync fails, and `onError()` never executes (either as an error callback or in the catch statement).

```
// Controller
function _onSyncClick() {
    return Pouch.sync()
        .then(deleteLocal, onError); // I do not want deleteLocal() to execute if Pouch.sync() fails
        .catch(onError); 
}


// Pouch service
function sync() {
    return 
        localDb.sync(remoteDb) 
            .on('error', function (err) {
                return $q.reject('Sync error.');
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`.synch()` uses a callback API, you can use `$q.when` and `$q.reject` to promisify it.

```
return localDB.sync(remoteDB).on('complete', function () {
   return $q.when("done!");
}).on('error', function (err) {
   return $q.reject(err);
});
```

Also, when chaining promises, you need to make sure you either `throw` an error or return a rejected promise, otherwise you will trigger the `resolve`/`success` handler.

so either `.on('error', errorHandler)` didn't ran as you though it would
or `Pouch.sync()` didn't invoke your function.

Comment: Thank you. I did return `$q.reject()` in my error handler, but the chained function still executed. Using breakpoints, I confirmed that the error handler was indeed reached, but `deleteLocal()` still executed after the error. Why did `$q.reject()` not break the chain?

Comment: i've accidentally used `.when` a second time, i've edited my answer

Comment: `but deleteLocal() still executed after the error.`, my guess is that the function was invoked by the `localDB.sync`. you can't run both success and reject handlers of a promise

Answer (score 0):

First your `then()` shouldn't call `deleteLocal` with `onError`.

Next, based on the Angular documentation: *If you "catch" an error via a promise error callback and you want to forward the error to the promise derived from the current promise, you have to "rethrow" the error by returning a rejection constructed via `$q.reject`*

So you are treating a callback event as a Promise and maybe that's why is not trowing a reject.

The properly way I think is Promisify the callback events from `sync()` using the `$q` constructor.

```
// Controller
function _onSyncClick() {
  return Pouch.sync().then(deleteLocal).catch(onError);
}

// Pouch Service, method sync
function sync() {
  return $q(function (resolve, reject) {
    localDb.sync(remoteDb, {
      // options
    }).on('complete', function (info) {
      resolve(info);
    }).on('error', function (err) {
      reject(err);
    });
  });
}
```

Just to mention, the `$q.when` wraps an object that might be a value or a (3rd party) then-able promise into a $q promise, don't use it as a resolve, use it to wrap the PouchDB promises.